# Help rewriting urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So what I am trying to do is create a website where the index.php will piece all the pages together with based upon parameters sent by query string.

I want to "rewrite" the urls from the form: http://example.com/index.php?p=cat1/page1 to something like http://example.com/cat1/page1

I am attempting to make use of .htaccess mod_rewrite rules, but have been unable to make anything work.

I know there are mountains of info on this stuff.. I have spent a few hours already reading about it and tinkering, but I feel stuck.  Nothing I am doing seems to yield any results.

Mod_rewrite IS loaded on the server (says phpinfo())

My .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([home|cat1|cat2]/)?([a-zA-Z]+_?)*/?$ /index.php?p=$1/$2 [L]
```

My index.php code:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_GET["p"])){
    $page = htmlspecialchars($_GET["p"]);
}else{
    $page = "home";
}

include('./template/header.php');

if (is_dir("./pages/$page")){
    include("./pages/$page/overview.php");
}else{
    if (file_exists("./pages/$page.php")){
        include("./pages/$page.php");
    }else{
        //not found
        echo '<h1 id="pageNotFound">Page Not Found</h1>';
    }
}
include('./template/footer.php');

?>
```

Comment: `include("./pages/$page.php")` this is a file inclusion vulnerability; you should filter `$page` by removing every non-alnum characters, or use a whitelist of allowed values for `$page`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your .htaccess fix:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt)$
RewriteRule ^(home|services)/([a-zA-Z_\-]+)(\/?)$ /NEP2/index.php?p=$1/$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

About the PHP, can you move the pages below the public_html folder?

Comment: Thank you!  I'll get to work patching that in there.  As for the pages move... for security I assume?  I'm kind of a newb when it comes to this, and was hoping someone might comment on the quality of my code and approach.  So thanks doubly.

Comment: @Zach, Yes you are right. By doing file_exists is very good. I would recommend to make sure the $page only contains letters, numbers and "/". You never see a URL with ½ or ± (SEO dont like that as well).

Comment: So... it still doesn't seem to work unfortunately.  http://localhost/NEP2/index.php?p=services/overview brings me to the correct page but http://localhost/NEP2/services/overview draws a blank [404]

Comment: where did you put your .htaccess? You might use "RewriteBase /" (without the ") right after RewriteEngine on

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but no dice.  the .htaccess is in /NEP2/ (same as index.php)

Comment: Lol, thanks!  Its not working perfectly yet, but at least I'm not getting a 404.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3557/discussion-between-book-of-zeus-and-zach-l)